# How to render every generated element of array immediately

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I generate 10000 strings. I add it to array and render it in html. Problem is that I need render each element when it's ready, not when all element are ready. How to id with vue2

```
<div id="app">
        <button @click="generateWords()">Generate words</button>
        <input v-model="search" type="text" />
        <ul>
            <li v-for="word in words" :key="word.id">
                {{ word }}
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>


<script>
export default {
    name: 'App',
    data() {
        return {
            words: [],
            count:10000,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        generateWords() {
            let symbols = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890';
            let word = '';
            for (let i = 0; count> i; i++) {
                while (word.length < 100) {
                    word += symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length)];
                }
                this.words.push(word);
                word = '';
            }
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: You're missing some fundamentals about vue performance.  It's the update of the whole words list in a view that takes most resources, not the update of words array. You should avoid this scenario for places where ui rensponsiveness is important. 10000 is a huge list. You can use virtual scroll if applicable.

Comment: @EstusFlask - Good point. :-)

Answer (score 2):

> ...I need render each element when it's ready, not when all element are ready...

You can't, if you generate the words synchronously on the main UI thread as you are above. (More below.) But note that generating 10,000 words the way you are above takes a modern JavaScript engine **very little time**. For instance, this takes less than 40ms on my machine:

```js
function generateWords() {
    let words = [];
    const count = 10000;
    let symbols = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
    let word = "";
    for (let i = 0; count > i; i++) {
        while (word.length < 100) {
            word += symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length)];
        }
        words.push(word);
        word = "";
    }
    return words;
}

console.time("x");
const w = generateWords();
console.timeEnd("x");
console.log(w.length);
```

The time generating the words isn't going to dominate your process, it's going to be the time *rendering* the words. As [Estus Flask says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77249442/how-to-render-every-generated-element-of-array-immediately/77249502#comment136185976_77249442), you probably want some kind of virtual scroll or similar, but it depends on your use case.

---

But answering the question that was asked, the reason you can't do the update if you generate the words synchronously on the main thread like that is that the thread that updates the UI is the same thread your JavaScript code runs on, and nothing else can run while your loop is running. You could move the generation to a [worker thread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker) and have it [post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage) each word (or small batches of words) to your Vue code as it generates them. Your Vue code running on the main UI thread would be free to render that word/those words even while the worker thread was still generating the others.

Here's a rough example of what the worker script might look like, based on your existing loop:

```
self.addEventListener("message", (e) => {
    if (e.data?.type === "start") {
        generateWords();
    }
});

function generateWords() {
    const count = 10000;
    let symbols = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
    let word = "";
    for (let i = 0; count > i; i++) {
        while (word.length < 100) {
            word += symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length)];
        }
        self.postMessage({ type: "word", word });
        word = "";
    }
}
```

Then the code to start the process and listen to the result:

```
const worker = new Worker("./worker.js");
worker.addEventListener("message", (e) => {
    if (e.data?.type === "word") {
        // ...use `e.data.word` here, it's the word that was received...
    }
});
worker.postMessage({ type: "start" });
```

You'll have to adapt that to fit with your Vue code, but that's the basic approach.

But again, the generation of the words probably isn't the problem.